# How to make a Javascript function that returns the contents of a text file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm sort of new to Javascript and AJAX and this would be very helpful as I'm having some trouble understanding this.

Basically I want a function that I can use like this:

```
var foo = loadFile(example.txt);
```

And have `foo` be the contents of the file.

Using JQuery is fine.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.get(url, function(result) {
  document.documentElement.innerHTML = result;
})
```

However the `url` must be on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with one line of code using the jQuery.load function. Basically you load the first argument is where you want the text to be inserted, the second is the location of the text file.

```
$( "#insert-text-file-into-here" ).load( "/example.txt" );
```

Comment: I want to put the text into a variable. Sorry, I should have written the question better, I edited it now.

Comment: If you want to load the text into a variable then sabof's answer is probably the simplest approach.